как настроить vs code как vs 2022 c++
Долгое время я спокойно сидел на VS 2022 и не имел проблем. Одной кнопкой "Локальный отладчик Windows" запускался код и я не имел проблем, но сейчас, когда мне потребовалось пользоваться гитом, появилась необходимость в VS Сode, и мне приходится сначала писать код в VS 2022, а потом копировать в VS Code чтобы отправить. Поэтому возникает вопрос:
Как нормально настроить VS Code чтобы дебагать.
Единстванное что, я смог собрать проект как-то с clang но это сборка а не дебаг (:
Да, я читал документацию VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) и всеравно ничего не понял.

Вообще git это отдельный софт и к ide не имеет никакого отношения? Зачем для пуша в git вы копируете код?

А что мешает пользоваться гитом в VS?

Я использую github desktop и от туда удобно открывать vs code. А пользоваться гитом из VS 2022 не понял как, т.к. от туда тоже проблема, наверное из-за теж же настроек дебага и компиляции, но уже в VS 2022.

"пользоваться гитом из VS 2022 не понял как, т.к. от туда тоже проблема" - ¿Какие действия остались непонятны? ¿Какие проблемы?

Могу только дать пару советов, т.к. по вашему вопросу можно мануал написать.
Сам VS code это просто текстовый редактор("продвинутый"), из-за этого в работе с ним возникают нюансы даже у людей, кто разбирается или даже работал уже в нем.

Настройка может занять много времени, даже у знающих людей, но есть плюс вы сможете понять как реально все собирается.
так же посоветую пользоваться и изучить cmake, если вы работаете с с++, без него никак не обойтись, это нужный навык в стеке, можете собирать и дебажить без него, но тогда у вас будут проблемки. Суть проблемки в том, что в отличии от VS в VScode надо все прописывать самому в итоге все пути тоже надо писать самому. Вам придется очень знатно покопаться и разобраться в компиляторе и его аргументах и знать, что нужно прописать.
вывод можете мучить, но лучше просто изучить cmake, скачайте расширение для него и запускайте и производите сборку через cmake, а не сразу через clang или gcc(но это все равно будет сложнее чем просто 1 кнопка в vs). Вот эти два:


Кроме того, чтобы работать с GIT не обязательно пользоваться именно интерфейсом, через консоль прекрасно работается и незачем переходить в VS code только ради интерфейса, на оф. сайте есть хорошая книга которая решит 90% случаев при работе с git("Progit"), можете почитать тут. Она уже переведена на русский.
Так же на этом же сайте, если уж очень надо есть список различных утилит именно графических для работы с git, как платных, так и бесплатных, так что еще раз повторюсь, не советую переходить на другую ide, только ради граф. раcширения для git(в книге глава А1.1 вот тут).
